# How to use eclipse plugin to create a new wizard for creating a project?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, wizard

I want to create a Project-Creating wizard in Eclipse.And the created project contains nothing 
except several folders.The question is how to write function "doFinish()" and function "performFinish()".

Answer (score 1):

You create a project with something like:

```java
IWorkspace workspace = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace();

IProject project = workspace.getRoot().getProject(name);

IProjectDescription projectDesc = workspace.newProjectDescription(name);

projectDesc.setLocation(null);  // Use default location

// TODO add any natures, builders, ... required to the project description

project.create(projectDesc, progress monitor);

project.open(progress monitor);

// TODO create any folders and files you want
```