# How to create files in New Project Creation Wizards

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

In my current project, I am trying to **create project (eclipse plugin project)** with four files having extension .mydsl (e.g.- vocab.mydsl, arch.mydsl & etc.) and want to **export that project as a Eclipse Plugin**. For that, I have created project (using eclipse plugin project) and exported as Plug-ins and Fragments in eclipse. I am attaching source code for better clarity.

```
package customplugin.wizards;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.IStructuredSelection;
import org.eclipse.jface.wizard.Wizard;
import org.eclipse.ui.INewWizard;
import org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbench;
import org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.WizardNewProjectCreationPage;

public class BuilderNewWizard extends Wizard implements INewWizard {

private WizardNewProjectCreationPage _pageOne;

public BuilderNewWizard() {
// Here I am adding Title of New Wizard
    setWindowTitle("IoT Suite");
}

@Override
public void init(IWorkbench workbench, IStructuredSelection selection) {
}

@Override
public boolean performFinish() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public void addPages() {
    super.addPages();
 // Here I am creating One Page with title and other attributes..
    _pageOne = new WizardNewProjectCreationPage("From Scratch Project Wizard");
    _pageOne.setTitle("IoT Suite Configuration");
    _pageOne.setDescription("Create IoTSuite Configuration");
    addPage(_pageOne);
  }
}
```

I am attaching link of image (it display project having name IoT in Project Wizard) because I am not able to upload image.
[Click Here for Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLqEv.png)
Now question is how to add action so that I can **add files to that Project**?? When I click on Finish than **Project is not imported to Eclipse Package Explorer window**. Am I missing something in `performFinish` method ??

Comment: Yes you need to actually do the work to create the project in the `performFinish`. This is quite a lot of code, look at the source of `org.eclipse.ui.wizards.newresource.BasicNewProjectResourceWizard`

Comment: @greg-449- Thanks for the pointer. Could you please elaborate more on this(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22278672/how-to-use-eclipse-plugin-to-create-a-new-wizard-for-creating-a-project) link answer posted by you ?? . I think your answer might be matched with my requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I **figure out the solution** and it **works perfectly**. Refer following code, where `doFinish` method, call `openContentStream` method with file name that we want to create. Here in `openContentStream` method we are creating desired file with predefined content. If we don't want any predefined content than set `content=null`.

```
private void doFinish(String containerName, String fileName, String title,
        IProgressMonitor monitor) throws CoreException {

    monitor.beginTask("Creating " + fileName, 2);
    IWorkspaceRoot root = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot();
    IResource resource = root.findMember(new Path(containerName));

    if (!resource.exists() || !(resource instanceof IContainer)) {
        throwCoreException("Container \"" + containerName
                + "\" does not exist.");
    }
    IContainer container = (IContainer) resource;

    final IFile file = container.getFile(new Path(fileName));
    try {

        InputStream stream = openContentStream(name);

        try {
            if (file.exists()) {
                file.setContents(stream, true, true, monitor);
            } else {
                file.create(stream, true, monitor);
            }
        } finally {
            stream.close();
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
    monitor.worked(1);
    monitor.setTaskName("Opening file for editing...");
    getShell().getDisplay().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench()
                    .getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();
            try {
                IDE.openEditor(page, file, true);
            } catch (PartInitException e) {
            }
        }
    });
    monitor.worked(1);
}

/**
 * Initialize the file contents to contents of the given resource.
 */
public static InputStream openContentStream(String name) throws CoreException {
    if(name.equals("vocab"))
    {
        contents=null;
         contents = "structs:                                                                                   "+
                 "\n/*  TempStruct                                                                              "+
                 "\n        tempValue: double;                                                                  "+
                 "\n        unitOfMeasurement : String;   */                                "+
                 "\nresources:                                                                                 "+
                 "\n    sensors:                                                                                "+
                 "\n        periodicSensors:                                                                    "+
                 "\n        /*  TemperatureSensor                                                               "+
                 "\n                generate tempMeasurement:TempStruct;                                        "+
                 "\n                sample period 1000 for 100000;    */                               "+
                 "\n        eventDrivenSensors:                                                                 "+
                 "\n        /*  SmokeDetector                                                                   "+
                 "\n                generate smokeMeasurement:SmokeStruct;                                      "+
                 "\n                onCondition smokeValue > 650 PPM ;     */                                     "+
                 "\n        requestBasedSensors:                                                                "+
                 "\n        /*  YahooWeatherService                                                             "+
                 "\n                generate weatherMeasurement:TempStruct accessed-by locationID : String; */    "+
                 "\n        tags:                                                                               "+
                 "\n        /*  BadgeReader                                                                     "+
                 "\n                generate badgeDetected: BadgeStruct;    */                                    "+
                 "\n        actuators:                                                                          "+
                 "\n        /*  Heater                                                               "+
                 "\n                action Off();                                                                          "+
                 "\n                action SetTemp(setTemp:TempStruct);     */                                    "+
                 "\n        storages:                                                                           "+
                 "\n        /*  ProfileDB                                                                       "+
                 "\n                generate profile:TempStruct accessed-by badgeID:String;  */                 "  ;    

    }
```